# Is there a general way to determine how many extraneous solutions a final equation will have after applying $n$ transformations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Is there a general method to determine this without plugging the solutions in the original equations? I assume non-injective transformations applied to the original equation.

Comment: Linear transformation?

Comment: @DavidP No, any transformation.

Comment: @DavidP I think OP means applying a function to both sides of an equation. E.g., going from $x=y$ to $x^2=y^2$. Anyway, applying a $k$-to-one map would introduce $k-1$ additional solutions. Many maps are not $k$-to-one, but if you know $\#f^{-1}(x) \leq k$ for any $x$, then applying $f$ would also introduce at most $k-1$ additional solutions. I don't think there is any hope of getting an answer in terms of $n$ for arbitrary function applications.

Comment: Applying $\sin(\cdot)$ to both sides of $x=0$ gives infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Although the squaring function is at most two-to-one, applying it to both sides of an equation with one solution can produce an equation with infinitely many solutions.  Thus
$$ x = -x$$ 
has only one solution, but 
$$ x^2 = (-x)^2$$ has infinitely many.